# Click doesn't always trigger toggle-event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position

I have sort of an imagemap, which is basically a lot of absolutely positioned divs, which, when clicked, will show or hide a tooltip. Looks pretty great, apart from the fact, that it doesn't always "work". It sounds silly, but some times I will have to click a couple of times to trigger the event. Maybe I'm just not clicking hard enough? ;)

**Markup**

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="img.png" />
  <div class="trigger"
    <div class="tooltip">
      Awesome tooltip is awesome!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Style**

```
.container {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative; }

img {
    position:relative; }

.trigger {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:50px; }

.tooltip {
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  position:absolute;
  top:35px;
  left:35px;
  display:none; }
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".trigger").toggle(function () {
      $(this).children(".tooltip").stop(true, true).fadeTo(200, 0.9);
      $(this).siblings(".trigger").children(".tooltip").stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
   }, function () {
      $(this).children(".tooltip").fadeOut(200);
   });
```

The markup and CSS is simplified, but imagine I have several tooltips over the image. When I open one tooltip, all others should be closed. I'm guessing this is where things go wrong, but I can't see the error.

In a similar function on the same site, I've semi-dynamically added some IDs, and hide all that is :not(ID), but I just can't believe that should be necessary.

**EDIT:**
Behold, a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CfYRv/

Comment: The trigger div's opening tag is missing the ending >.

Comment: Ah, nevermind that. It's not copied off the source, I just simplified it here. Making a fiddle instead.

Comment: I updated the question with a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CfYRv/

Comment: Using last chrome stable, the event never fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gah!  Need to finish my homework, but long answer short: toggle doesn't work here because you toggle a submenu but then click another.  this hides the first submenu, but it's still considered open (it was only hidden).  Thus you need to click it twice to open it... I hacked together an alternative but it's not the best code. It'll at least give you an idea what needs done:

http://jsfiddle.net/uj2A4/

```
$(".trigger").click(function () {
      if($(this).hasClass("active"))
          $(".tooltip",this).fadeOut(200);
      else {
          $(this).children(".tooltip").stop(true, true).fadeTo(200, 0.9);
          $(this).siblings(".trigger").children(".tooltip").stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
      }
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
      $(this).siblings(".trigger").removeClass("active");
   });
```

Comment: Yeah, I usually use a similar solution, I just thought .toggle() looked cleaner. Too bad it's not usable. :(
Anyway, cheers.

Comment: @Nix sorry I can't think of anything else... there should be a way to programatically change the toggle state of an element, but I don't know what that would be.

Answer (score 2):

change your javascript to something like

```
$(".trigger").click(function () {
      $(".tooltip").fadeOut();
      $(this).children(".tooltip").fadeIn();
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than toggle, let's use click: http://jsfiddle.net/CfYRv/3/

This assigns the "active" tooltip a css class "ttactive". Clicking on "some trigger" will fade out every active tooltip, and activate the one you just clicked. If the one you just clicked was the active one, all it does is fade that one out.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably still use toggle this way:

```
 $(".trigger").click(function () {
  $(this).children(".tooltip").stop(true, true).toggle();
  $(this).siblings(".trigger").children(".tooltip").stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
 });
```